# python pivot table - adding another column

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

We want to create a pivot table using SQL Server ,and also we want to calculate the Growth Percentage of last two days.

Here is the code for pivot table using SQL Server.

```
data=pd.read_sql_query("select CONVERT(varchar,created_on,111) as Date,service_name as TFN,isnull(count(*),0) MC_Count from tablename with(nolock) where created_on>=cast(getdate()-1 as date) and user_Id='xxx' group by CONVERT(varchar,created_on,111),service_name",con)

P=pd.pivot_table(data,index="TFN",columns="Date",values=["MC_Count"],aggfunc={"MC_Count":np.sum})
```

I want to add  another column with Increase in Percentage but I don't know how.

Format:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: if u wish to add an array named "a" just do a data["new_column"]=a
if u wish to create an empty column just do a data.insert(loc=4,column="new_column,value=None)

Comment: Are you looking for something like `P['last_two_days_growth%'] = (P['18-Jul-18']-P['15-Jul-18'])/P['15-Jul-18']*100`

Answer (score 0):

You can select columns by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), subtract, divide and multiple by `100`:

```
P['growth%'] = ((P.iloc[:, -1] -  P.iloc[:, -2]) / P.iloc[:, -2]) * 100
print (P)
         15-Jul-18  16-Jul-18  18-Jul-18  growth%
1800XXX        789        800       1009   26.125
18001XX        890        900        900    0.000
```